# ui-router $state.includes matching all descendants but not parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to match all of a state's descendant states, but not the state itself. e.g. I want to match `about.person.item` and `about.person` but not `about`.

I would like to use the following globbing pattern:

```js
$state.includes('about.*.**');
```

But this fails to match.

This appears to be expected behaviour, as the following test fails when added to the [state spec file](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/test/stateSpec.js#L605-L618) (which tests against the current state of `about.person.item`).

```js
expect($state.includes('about.*.**')).toBe(true);
```

I can accomplish what I need with a `$state.includes('about.**') && !$state.is('about')` but it feels clunky.

Is this expected behaviour for glob matching?

**Note**: I have determined a fix to make this work which does not break other tests for reference: https://github.com/jonotron/ui-router/commit/e39b27a2cb7d88525c446a041f9fbf1553202010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug. I've since patched with this PR: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1680 which has been merged into master.